# Removing tray icon from panel, into the expanded tray menu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, system-tray

I want to hide the tray icon of my qt5 script in python to appear in the expanded box, (as the "Always Hidden" setting usually would in KDE5), rather than directly on the taskbar.

[image: Like this]

QSystemTrayIcon.hide() would hide it entirely out of view. In the tray settings I can't change visibility either, probably because it's not a permanent entry, the dropdown is greyed out.

Comment: You can't do that programmatically, as it is managed by the OS, Qt can only show or hide the icon, that's it. Did you set a proper [`applicationName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) and [`organizationName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) for the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without implementing a KDE plasma applet(plasmoid). For details, see [Plasmoids](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-desktop/-/blob/v5.27.5/design/plasmoids), [Notification Area (Systemtray)](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/DeveloperGuide#Notification_Area_(Systemtray)), and
[Plasma PulseAudio Applet](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-pa).